# ConseilJS Tutorial installing fails

Tags: conseil, conseiljs

I wanted to start with the [ConseilJS tutorial](https://github.com/Cryptonomic/ConseilJS-Tutorials) from Cryptonomic but when I try to install node modules after I cloned the repository the install suddenly stops. First I was thinking that its just slow because of my old computer. But its just stuck and I dont know why. Does it work for anyone else? Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: It's not clear exactly where you are getting stuck, so it is hard to help you without replicating the whole process to see whether it's just you or not.
Can you provide some more details, ideally a snippet of the installation logs where it's getting stuck.

Comment: I can provide a screenshot but not sure if it will help.
This are my steps: 
1. git clone https://github.com/Cryptonomic/ConseilJS-Tutorials.git

2. cd ConseilJS-Tutorials

3. git checkout web-wallet/start

4. npm install

After starting npm install it suddenly just freezes and nothing is happening. I tried several times without success.